# Control Atomic Transactions in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, atomic

I have a simple library application. In order to force 3 actions to commit as one action, and rollback if any of the actions fail, I made the following code changes:

In `settings.py`:

```
AUTOCOMMIT=False
```

In `forms.py`

```
from django.db import IntegrityError, transaction
    class CreateLoan(forms.Form):
        #Fields...
        def save(self):
            id_book = form.cleaned_data.get('id_book', None)
            id_customer = form.cleaned_data.get('id_customer', None)
            start_date = form.cleaned_data.get('start_date', None)
            book = Book.objects.get(id=id_book)
            customer = Customer.objects.get(id=id_customer)
            new_return = Return(
                book=book
                start_date=start_date)
            txn=Loan_Txn(
                customer=customer,
                book=book,
                start_date=start_date
            )

            try
                with transaction.atomic():
                    book.update(status="ON_LOAN")
                    new_return.save(force_insert=True)
                    txn.save(force_insert=True)
            except IntegrityError:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Something occured. Please try again")
```

Am I still missing anything with regards to this? I'm using Django 1.9 with Python 3.4.3 and the database is MySQL.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry to close the loop, can i ask why `AUTOCOMMIT=False` does not help with the query? Is it correct to say that, by default, `AUTOCOMMIT=True` and for all transactions that are not wrapped in an `atomic` block, they will just execute and commit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `transaction.atomic()` correctly (including putting the `try ... except` outside the transaction) but you should definitely not be setting `AUTOCOMMIT = False`.

As the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#autocommit) states, you set that system-wide setting to `False` when you want to "disable Django’s transaction management"—but that's clearly *not* what you want to do, since you're using `transaction.atomic()`! More from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#deactivating-transaction-management):

> If you do this, Django won’t enable autocommit, and won’t perform any commits. You’ll get the regular behavior of the underlying database library.
>   This requires you to commit explicitly every transaction, even those started by Django or by third-party libraries. Thus, this is best used in situations where you want to run your own transaction-controlling middleware or do something really strange.

So just don't do that. Django will of course disable autocommit for that atomic block and re-enable it when the block finishes.